# bootstrap data table showing and pagination not inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

### bootstrap data table code

how we can set this code

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-5">
    <div class="dataTables_info" id="example_info" role="status" aria-live="polite">
        Showing 1 to 10 of 28 entries
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-7">
    <div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers" id="example_paginate">
        <ul class="pagination">
            <li class="paginate_button previous disabled" id="example_previous">
                <a href="#" aria-controls="example" data-dt-idx="0" tabindex="0">Previous</a>
            </li>

            <li class="paginate_button active">
                <a href="#" aria-controls="example" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0">1</a>
            </li>

            <li class="paginate_button ">
                <a href="#" aria-controls="example" data-dt-idx="2" tabindex="0">2</a>
            </li>

            <li class="paginate_button ">
                <a href="#" aria-controls="example" data-dt-idx="3" tabindex="0">3</a>
            </li>

            <li class="paginate_button next" id="example_next">
                <a href="#" aria-controls="example" data-dt-idx="4" tabindex="0">Next</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

### This code are apply but not work this code

```
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button {
    padding : 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    display: inline;
    border: 0px;
}
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button:hover {
    border: 0px;
}
```

### image upload for help

[image: for your help]

how can solve this problem please help me in this task...!

Answer (score 0):

Try following in definition

```
"dom": '<ip<b>>'
```